# why pageshow not call in jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me why  pageshow event not call in jquery mobile?
http://jsfiddle.net/G7AvE/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#1").on('pagebeforeshow ', function() {
        //YourFunctionCall();
    alert('1')
    });
});

jQuery( "#1" ).on( "pageshow", function( event ) { alert('1') } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refrain from using `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile, use `pageinit` instead. Moreover, for *page* id, don't use *plain digits*; an `id` should contain characters.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageID", function () {
  $("#pageID").on('pagebeforeshow ', function () {
    /* run code */
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/G7AvE/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

At top left, the dropdown below Frameworks and Extensions. Change from `onload` to `No Wrap- in <body>`

> **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/G7AvE/2/)**

In jsFiddle this makes sure the libraries are loaded before your code tries to use them.